# How to pass date in file name to get saved in required directory using autoIt selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, autoit

I am using autoIt to handle the saveAs dialog box in selenium java.
Here, I should save the pdf file in required directory

```
ControlFocus("Save As","","Edit1")
ControlSend("Save As","","Edit1","-----My file path\file_name.pdf")
ControlClick("Save As","","Button2")
```

Is it possible to add today's date or last weekend date(Saturday) in my file name and send in the file path to get saved?

Comment: Sure, just find today's date, convert it to string and use it in the file name. What actual problem are you facing? (See [ask].)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help you out?

```
#include<date.au3>
Dim $Y, $M, $D
$today = _DateTimeFormat(_NowCalc(), 2)
ConsoleWrite($today & @CRLF ) ; Regional settings today
$today_format = @YEAR &'-' & @MON & '-' & @MDAY
ConsoleWrite($today_format & @CRLF ) ; fixed format today
$lastSaturday = _DayValueToDate(_DateToDayValue(@YEAR, @MON, @MDAY) - _DateToDayOfWeek(@YEAR, @MON, @MDAY), $Y, $M, $D)
ConsoleWrite($lastSaturday & @CRLF) ; last SATURDAY

$yourPathWithDate = "My file path\" & $today_format & "_file_name.pdf"
ConsoleWrite($yourPathWithDate & @CRLF)

ControlFocus("Save As","","Edit1")
ControlSend("Save As","","Edit1","My file path\file_name.pdf")
ControlClick("Save As","","Button2")
```